# Access Denied with Amazon CloudFront private distribution

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm am trying to setup CloudFront for private content distribution but I keep getting Access Denied errors when I follow the generated URL. To be clear, I have already created the CloudFront distribution, marked it private, created an Origin Access ID which has been given read permission to all the relevant files.

I'v written a simple Python script to generate the URLs using the examples presented on the Amazon webpage for signing URLs and am including the text below:

```
import os, time

def GetCloudFrontURL(file, expires=86400):
  resource = "http://mydistribution.cloudfront.net/" + file
  exptime = int(time.time()) + expires
  epochtime = str(exptime)
  policy = '{"Statement":[{"Resource":"' + resource + '","Condition":{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":' + epochtime + '}}}]}'
  pk = "MY-PK-GOES-HERE"
  signature = os.popen("echo '" + policy + "' | openssl sha1 -sign /path/to/file/pk-" + pk + ".pem | openssl base64 | tr '+=/' '-_~'").read()
  signature = signature.replace('\n','')
  url = resource + "&Expires=" + epochtime + "&Signature=" + signature + "&Key-Pair-Id=" + pk
  return url
```

Can anybody see anything obviously wrong with what I am doing? I've verified that when I sign the digest using the private key that I can verify it with the public key (provided I do the verification before feeding it through base64 and the translation step).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Running your method I get an ampersand before the first keywork, Expires.

```
>>> GetCloudFrontURL('test123')
http://mydistribution.cloudfront.net/test123&Expires=1297954193&Signature=&Key-Pair-Id=MY-PK-GOES-HERE
```

Don't know if it solves your whole problem but I suspect you need question mark in the URL to get the params to parse properly. Try something like this:

```
url = resource + "?Expires=" + epochtime + "&Signature=" + signature + "&Key-Pair-Id=" + pk
```

Aside, the urllib.urlencode method will convert a dictionary of params into a URL for you. http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode

Comment: That definitely looks like it might be an issue, but unfortunately, I'm still getting the access denied error.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this, I was able to get it working with a few tweaks.

Also, see boto's set_all_permissions function that will set you S3 ACL's automatically for you.

```
from OpenSSL.crypto import *
import base64
import time
from django.conf import settings

ALT_CHARS = '-~' 

def get_cloudfront_url(file, expires=86400):
    resource = "https://" + settings.AWS_CLOUDFRONT_URL + "/" + file
    exptime = int(time.time()) + expires

    epochtime = str(exptime)
    policy = '{"Statement":[{"Resource":"' + resource + '","Condition":{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":' + epochtime + '}}}]}'

    f = open(settings.AWS_PRIVATE_KEY, 'r')
    private_key = load_privatekey(FILETYPE_PEM, f.read())
    f.close()

    signature = base64.b64encode(sign(private_key, policy, 'sha1'), ALT_CHARS)
    signature = signature.replace('=', '_')

    url = resource + "?Expires=" + epochtime + "&Signature=" + signature + "&Key-Pair-Id=" + settings.AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY_PAIR_ID
    return url
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can generate signed URLs without having to os.popen to openssl.  This uses the excellent M2Crypto python library

This code is based loosely on the PHP example code provided by Amazon in the CloudFront documentation.

```
from M2Crypto import EVP
import base64
import time

def aws_url_base64_encode(msg):
    msg_base64 = base64.b64encode(msg)
    msg_base64 = msg_base64.replace('+', '-')
    msg_base64 = msg_base64.replace('=', '_')
    msg_base64 = msg_base64.replace('/', '~')
    return msg_base64

def sign_string(message, priv_key_string):
    key = EVP.load_key_string(priv_key_string)
    key.reset_context(md='sha1')
    key.sign_init()
    key.sign_update(message)
    signature = key.sign_final()
    return signature

def create_url(url, encoded_signature, key_pair_id, expires):
    signed_url = "%(url)s?Expires=%(expires)s&Signature=%(encoded_signature)s&Key-Pair-Id=%(key_pair_id)s" % {
            'url':url,
            'expires':expires,
            'encoded_signature':encoded_signature,
            'key_pair_id':key_pair_id,
            }
    return signed_url

def get_canned_policy_url(url, priv_key_string, key_pair_id, expires):
    #we manually construct this policy string to ensure formatting matches signature
    canned_policy = '{"Statement":[{"Resource":"%(url)s","Condition":{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":%(expires)s}}}]}' % {'url':url, 'expires':expires}

    #now base64 encode it (must be URL safe)
    encoded_policy = aws_url_base64_encode(canned_policy)
    #sign the non-encoded policy
    signature = sign_string(canned_policy, priv_key_string)
    #now base64 encode the signature (URL safe as well)
    encoded_signature = aws_url_base64_encode(signature)

    #combine these into a full url
    signed_url = create_url(url, encoded_signature, key_pair_id, expires);

    return signed_url

def encode_query_param(resource):
    enc = resource
    enc = enc.replace('?', '%3F')
    enc = enc.replace('=', '%3D')
    enc = enc.replace('&', '%26')
    return enc


#Set parameters for URL
key_pair_id = "APKAIAZVIO4BQ" #from the AWS accounts CloudFront tab
priv_key_file = "cloudfront-pk.pem" #your private keypair file
# Use the FULL URL for non-streaming:
resource = "http://34254534.cloudfront.net/video.mp4"
#resource = 'video.mp4' #your resource (just object name for streaming videos)
expires = int(time.time()) + 300 #5 min

#Create the signed URL
priv_key_string = open(priv_key_file).read()
signed_url = get_canned_policy_url(resource, priv_key_string, key_pair_id, expires)

print(signed_url)

#Flash player doesn't like query params so encode them if you're using a streaming distribution
#enc_url = encode_query_param(signed_url)
#print(enc_url)
```

Make sure that you set up your distribution with a TrustedSigners parameter set to the account holding your keypair (or "Self" if it's your own account)

See [Getting started with secure AWS CloudFront streaming with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549787/getting-started-with-secure-aws-cloudfront-streaming-with-python/6590986#6590986) for a fully worked example on setting this up for streaming with Python